# How much Bluegleam is there to collect?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn, horizon-zero-dawn-the-frozen-wilds

Banuk special merchants have three new bows and four new armours that you can buy for a new resource called "bluegleam". It can be found on old machines (there is a map) and gained as reward for quests.

Is there enough of it to get all three bows and four armours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](https://www.vg247.com/2017/11/06/horizon-zero-dawn-the-frozen-wilds-bluegleam/) contains a extensive list of quest rewards and machine locations where to obtain Bluegleam. While the article states their quest list is incomplete, the very bottom of the page says

> Hopefully between the quest rewards and open world Bluegleam formations this is all you need to know to collect all the Bluegleam you could ever need in Horizon Zero Dawn: The Frozen Wilds – **it was enough for us to purchase all three Banuk weapons and the four new outfits, anyway!**

(emphasis my own)